# Is there a collection of teaching materials?

Tags: education, teaching

Is there anywhere that I can find a collection of teaching materials for the Raspberry Pi?

I would hope this could include details such as:

1. Flashing the SD card.
2. Installing the basic OS.
3. Programming the GPIO.
4. Software recommendations for teaching programming skills.

Lesson plans or anything similar that are available would be very interesting.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed, given that education is the primary goal of the foundation

Comment: @Alex, that makes it on-topic for the forum, but not for a Q+A site.

Comment: Though maybe it is "too localized" rather than "not constructive"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not teaching materials as such, the [elinux](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Hub#Beginners_Guide) wiki has many tutorials which should be fairly easy to convert into lesson plans.

The Raspberry Pi Foundation have stated in many interviews that they are working with other groups in order to release lesson plans.

Answer (score 3):

[Computing at School](http://www.computingatschool.org.uk/index.php?id=cacfs) are actively working on a curriculum and lesson plans.

Comment: Do you have a source for that information?

Comment: The link details their curriculum, but the lesson plans are hear say.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the raspberry pi official site,
There is a page where you can download MagPi magazines for free and keep them in sdcard.