# Is there a central resource for project ideas?

Tags: tutorial, teaching

Is there a community-accepted space that people are submitting their finished projects (for example, [Ben Heck's BBC Micro mod](http://benheck.com/07-09-2012/raspberry-pi-project), The [SNESDev-RPi](http://petrockblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/snesdev-rpi-a-snes-adapter-for-the-raspberry-pi/#more-294), etc.)?  How-tos would be nice, but not required.

For enterprising hackers that are looking to borrow ideas from others that have done projects, this would be a great resource and it would also be fun for uber-geeks to show off their skills.

I can continue to browse the Internet and YouTube for finished projects and project ideas, but I was wondering if there was a single place that aggregated a repository of Raspberry Pi ideas in a more friendly format.

If this doesn't exist, please indicate as such.

Comment: This question is now considered acceptable in its current form and has been reopened. You can read why [at this meta answer](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/235/raspberry-pi-information-outside-of-the-stackexchange-scope).

Comment: As @Jivings said, your question has been reopened. Thank you for taking the time to improve it. We need more users like you if we are going to graduate. =D

Comment: The closest thing I've seen is http://hackaday.com/category/rasberry-pi/ .Well its not Raspberry Pi specific.

Comment: This really seems like something the foundation need to take hold of - a proper library/wiki with everything tagged etc would be a valuable resource.

Comment: This too http://www.raspberryprojects.com but it seems empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find existing projects with instructions?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/where-can-i-find-existing-projects-with-instructions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The confusing thing about the Raspberry Pi wiki is that they have it hosted at elinux.org.  That being said they do have sections dedicated to Projects, Guides, and Tutorials which all combined I think meet your expectations.  The only problem is that the Projects page only has a a dozen or so projects.

I think we ought to help the Raspberry Pi Foundation out with their Projects Page adoption rate by vocally advertising its existence.

See the [Projects, Guides, and Tutorials](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Hub#Projects.2C_Guides_.26_Tutorials) section here.

The actual [Projects page](http://elinux.org/RPi_Projects) is here.

Comment: I think this was exactly what Zoot was looking for.

Comment: I think you're right.  It's not complete, but I think it's as official as we can get at this point.